# Installing a program in OS X using "make install" without being superuser?

Tags: macos, installation, unix, sudo, make

I'm trying to install the Insight debugger on OS X with "make install" but my permissions aren't high enough and I'm always denied. Is there any way to install without having/being a superuser? I have an admin account but I'm not sure how that can help me.

Edit:

Following the answer below `./configuration --prefix=/path/` works but the first `make` command dumps a huge amount of errors ending in

```
make[3]: *** [wish] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-tk] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea what the non-tk errors are?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you just need to configure the build and release process it to use a prefix other than one that requires root access on your machine. When you run `./configure` you can point the entire installation process to use a directory you have access to by supplying the `--prefix` option. Lets say you want to install in to `~/insight`, you'd run:

```
./configure --prefix=~/insight
make
make test
make install
```

The install process will take care of creating `~/insight/[lib,bin,man,etc.]` under your home directory for you.

You can get a list of configuration options that the `./configure` script for your tool supports by doing:

```
./configure --help
```

Comment: You might want to set up your own user directory for UNIX programs (somewhere like `~/usr/`, which simplifies adding everything to your `PATH` later.